# how to pass dynamic input pararm to gradle java exec task?

Tags: java, gradle

I have this Gradle task:

```
task resources_cleaner_bl(type: JavaExec) {
    classpath sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    systemProperties['cleanTarget'] = 'bl'
    main = "com.m.ResourcesCleanerRunner"
}
```

How can I edit this such that `'bl'` will be entered dynamically when I run this gradle task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply eliminate the configuration `systemProperties['cleanTarget'] = 'bl'` by setting the system property from the command line using the `-D` flag, i.e. running `gradlew resources_cleaner_bl -DcleanTarget=bl`.

You can read more about project and system properties in Gradle user guide **[here](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_properties_and_system_properties)**.

Comment: If you want to pass it as args to the java process then you can add a `args` property and set it to `systemProperties['cleanTarget']`. You can find more information about passing arguments to tasks of type JavaExec in **[here](https://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html)**.